# React Native PDF Preview

Tags: android, react-native, pdf

I want to develope a pdf printing app in React Native.
In preview page, I should show a pdf file in a view.
I tried this tutorial https://www.pdftron.com/blog/mobile/how-to-build-a-pdf-viewer-react-native/  but when I put `react-native link react-native-view-pdf` I get error `unknown command 'link'`.
So, I ignored this command and tried `npx react-native run-android` but I got error.
The emulator shows red screen with error `can't find module "3"`...

This is the react native code in that tutorial I tried.

```
import PDFView from 'react-native-view-pdf';

const resources = {
  file: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'test-pdf.pdf' : '/sdcard/Download/test-pdf.pdf',
  url: 'https://www.ets.org/Media/Tests/TOEFL/pdf/SampleQuestions.pdf',
  base64: 'JVBERi0xLjMKJcfs...',
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const resourceType = 'base64';

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {/* Some Controls to change PDF resource */}
        <PDFView
          fadeInDuration={250.0}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          resource={resources[resourceType]}
          resourceType={resourceType}
          onLoad={() => console.log(`PDF rendered from ${resourceType}`)}
          onError={() => console.log('Cannot render PDF', error)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add the error log to the question.